# posix signal reaction time

Tags: c++, linux, qt, signals, timing

**What is a reasonable reaction time to posix signals intending to quit the application?**

In other words, how long may my *sigint*, *sigterm* or *sigtstp* handling take before the system kills the application during shutdown, runlevel switching or other automated situations?

I'm writing a non graphical qt application that has to respond to signals in order to clean up before terminating. this is my current implementation:

```
#include "posixsignals.h"
#include <signal.h>

QAtomicInt posixSignals::sig(0);

posixSignals::posixSignals()
{

    //connect to posix signals
        signal(SIGINT, posixSignals::interrupt);
        signal(SIGTSTP, posixSignals::interrupt);
        signal(SIGTERM, posixSignals::interrupt);

    //connect and start QTimer t
        connect(&t, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(check()));
        t.start(500);
}

void posixSignals::interrupt(int signal)
{
    sig.testAndSetOrdered(0,signal);
}

void posixSignals::check()
{
    if(sig)
        emit signalCought(sig);
}
```

In the actual implementation i connect something to the signalCought signal in order to trigger the cleanup and exit of the application. the "problem" here is if i set the timer too low the app maxes a core, but if i set it too high, it might be killed or slow down the shutdown process noticeably.

Comment: Usually the system does not at all kill a application which catches `SIGTERM`. AFAIK there is nothing in the POSIX standard which requires the system to kill an application not responding. Some window managers provide this functionality (Gnome, KDE), some init systems provide functions for that (killproc, startproc, depends on the init system/distro). But if you start your app outside, nothing but a `SIGKILL` will actually kill it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using [`init(8)`](http://man.he.net/man8/init), scripts in `/etc/init.d/` are being used to stop processes. I believe the exact mechanism as well as timing constraints may vary from distribution to distribution. In my case, the time is set to 3 seconds (you can find it in `/etc/rc.d/init.d/functions` file inside a `killproc()` function. So 3 seconds is an upper limit in general.

This parameter can also be overridden by start/stop scripts of any particular daemon/application. There are also alternatives to `init.d`, `systemd` for instance. But I am not sure how that system works so cannot tell about timeouts.

I think 3 seconds is more than enough to stop any application — it is hard to imagine what can take longer than that. In the worse case scenario — just maintain some logs to see whether your application makes it on time or not.

Hope it helps.

Comment: it's not that the processing itself takes a long time, i'm just wondering how high i can set my polling interval since i'm using a flag to check if signals have arrived. setting it too high would be a waste of cpu, setting it too low causes it to be terminated mid-cleanup.

Comment: systemd has a 5 second timeout for all children to die.

Comment: @Hatagashira: Can't you immediate post a message to Qt's dispatch loop  once you receive a signal? Having sleep + poll cycles doesn't sounds like the best way to go about it.

Comment: @vlad i havent tried, but it seems like that would be as hassle as signal handling functions need to be re entrant and static. i'm going to try that anyways now, as polling isn't a neat solution.

Comment: @Hatagashira: They actually have to be asynchronous-safe. But there are other way to dispatch signals, where handlers can do whatever they want and then its not a hassle. It depends what Qt is using... Check if it allows you to register file descriptors, and if so — use `signalfd` (http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/signalfd.2.html)

Comment: Marked as the answer because you actually answered the question instead of telling me how i should implement my signals =D!

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a polling loop, you could use sockets with a QSocketNotifier to translate the posix signals into Qt events, as described [here](http://doc.qt.digia.com/qt/unix-signals.html).

Comment: i wanted to try the simplest and smallest solution i could think of first, but i'll look into that. apart from whether or not polling is the best way to go about it, it's nice to know what things like systemd do with programs that respond slowly to signals.